# Laravel - Elixir - Concat and Minify assets

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I have a project with a lot of `js` and `css` and I want to concat and minify them.
The problem is that I do not need all the scripts and css in all the pages so in my view I have a section which load the right assets for the page.

How can I use `Elixir` to minify resources for each page? is it possibile?
Can I concat, minify and versioning different assets and references to them in my view?

How can I do that?

Comment: well the first thing is come to my mind is to group all files that you're using on all pages and then sub-group with this logic,is this something that sounds good for you?

Comment: Yes, I have some asset that are common in all pages and I can concat them with elixir, but I do not find any infos about how to manage the other views, does elixir provide a helper for multiple file version?

Comment: not sure if you need,I'll post some example below maybe that'll be something that you find useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
......

//main js 
mix.scripts([
    ...
    ...
    ...
], publicJs + 'main.js');

//some js that are for about page
mix.scripts([

], publicJs + 'about.js);


mix.version([
    publicJs + 'main.js',publicJs + 'about.js'
]);
```

and for example if there are some files that are common for about and pricing pages i.e., then you can group them toghether too

```
mix.scripts([
   ...
   ...
],publicJs + 'someGrouped.js);

mix.scripts([
   ...
   ...
],publicJs + 'someOtherGrouped.js);

mix.scripts([
   '../../' + publicJs + 'someGrouped.js,
   '../../' + publicJs + 'someOtherGrouped.js,
   ...
],publicJs + 'grouped.js);
```

also you need to run

```
gulp --production
```

to minify all css and js files